# Find Percentage using Aggregation Function MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, relation

So I have a 3 tables `properties`, `property_plots` and `orders`. Each property will have many plots and each plot can have size with no_sqyds.
Now users can purchase plot with quantity `no_sqyds` which I am storing in `orders` table.

### `properties`

[image]

### `property_plots`

[image: id | property_id | no_sqyds]

### `orders`

[image: id | property_id | plot_id | no_sqyds]

So my question is how can I find the percent of purchase for particular plot ? Also how can I find the percent of purchase for entire property using same ?

So far what I tried is to find the percent at plot level using this rough query

```
((SELECT sum(o.no_sqyds) FROM orders as o 
WHERE o.plot_id = pp.id)*100)/pp.no_sqyds FROM property_plots as pp
```

Based on table `orders` table I can get percent for each plot but I am also looking at property level by combining this below data. (I have to get avg of this all plot percent to find at property level?)

```
plot_id 1 = 100% purchase

plot_id 2 = 66.67% purchase

plot_id 3 = 50%
```

Sample DB - https://pastebin.com/RYJwwRqJ

Comment: Provide your tables as CREATE TABLE scripts. Provide some sample data as INSERT INTO scripts and desired output for this data.

Comment: @Akina I have update the question. Please have a look also added the expected outcome based on dummy data in the table. Thanks

Comment: Screenshots does not make sense - they does not allow to copy SQL code and to reproduce your structure and data.

Comment: Okay I have added the Sample DB link in the question.

Comment: Next time provide your sample data as online fiddle (like 1st code block in my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join them and group them and calculate.

```
SELECT 
  property_id
, prop.name AS property_name
, (SUM(order_no_sqyds)/SUM(plot_no_sqyds))*100 AS percentage
, SUM(plot_no_sqyds) AS plot_no_sqyds
, SUM(order_no_sqyds) AS order_no_sqyds
, COUNT(plot_id) AS total_plots
, SUM(total_orders) AS total_orders
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      plot.property_id
    , plot.id AS plot_id
    , plot.no_sqyds AS plot_no_sqyds
    , SUM(ordr.no_sqyds) AS order_no_sqyds
    , COUNT(DISTINCT ordr.id) AS total_orders
    FROM property_plots AS plot
    LEFT JOIN orders AS ordr
      ON ordr.plot_id = plot.id
     AND ordr.property_id = plot.property_id
    GROUP BY 
      plot.property_id
    , plot.id
    , plot.no_sqyds
) q
INNER JOIN properties AS prop
   ON prop.id = q.property_id
GROUP BY property_id, prop.name
ORDER BY property_id
```

| property_id | property_name | percentage | plot_no_sqyds | order_no_sqyds | total_plots | total_orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lake View Park | 66.6667 | 225 | 150 | 3 | 4 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=34c8028a4ee699dc68c4e82f8abdfd4a)*

An other way to calculate it is by joining to an aggregation of the orders.

```
SELECT 
  plot.property_id
, prop.name AS property_name
, (SUM(ordr.no_sqyds)/SUM(plot.no_sqyds))*100 AS percentage
, SUM(plot.no_sqyds) AS plot_no_sqyds
, SUM(ordr.no_sqyds) AS order_no_sqyds
, COUNT(DISTINCT plot.id) AS total_plots
, SUM(total_orders) AS total_orders
FROM property_plots AS plot
INNER JOIN properties AS prop
   ON prop.id = plot.property_id
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT plot_id, property_id
   , SUM(no_sqyds) AS no_sqyds
   , COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS total_orders
   FROM orders
   GROUP BY plot_id, property_id
) AS ordr
  ON ordr.plot_id = plot.id
 AND ordr.property_id = plot.property_id
GROUP BY 
  plot.property_id
, prop.name
```

Plots only

```
SELECT 
  plot.property_id
, plot.id AS plot_id
, (SUM(ordr.no_sqyds)/plot.no_sqyds)*100 AS percentage
, plot.no_sqyds AS plot_no_sqyds
, SUM(ordr.no_sqyds) AS order_no_sqyds
, COUNT(DISTINCT ordr.id) AS total_orders
FROM property_plots AS plot
LEFT JOIN orders AS ordr
  ON ordr.plot_id = plot.id
 AND ordr.property_id = plot.property_id
GROUP BY 
  plot.property_id
, plot.id
, plot.no_sqyds
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it seems the query does not return as expected. It returns 3 rows for property id 1 and percent 100, 150 and 200 respectively

Comment: And is it ok now?

Comment: it results percentage of each plot this is correct but I need percent for entire property i.e property_id. It gives 100,66,50 for each plot but what if I want total property %. I guess it would be (100,66,50)/3=72 not sure though

Comment: It needed an extra group by

Comment: Yup I got it just trying to integrate it with my code and lets see how it goes. But seems perfect for my problem. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT orders.plot_id, 
       ROUND(100*SUM(orders.no_sqyds)/MAX(property_plots.no_sqyds)) purchase_percent
FROM orders
JOIN property_plots ON orders.plot_id = property_plots.id
GROUP BY orders.plot_id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=4c2bad2ff341ba94b3df2f278d1d7778

Comment: Thanks and how can i get percentage for property_id 1 from this 3 results ?

Comment: @AbhiBurk This is another grouping level. And another task. Create another question, provide sample data as a fiddle with 2-3 different properties and desired output for this sample data.